# where is the system logs and recent entries

Tags: 12.04

I want to get system login logs in ubuntu 12.04 lts for last month as well as history like windows system.Please guide & help.

Jyoti

Answer (score 1):

All system log's is in `/var/log`

You have explanation for each log [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles)

Answer (score 0):

You can list login information from the current month using this command as root

```
last -a
```

And for the previous month, you need to check the previous file

```
last -a -f /var/log/wtmp.1
```

For unsuccessful logins run

```
lastb -a
```

Check `man last` for more information.